# How to pass JS Remoting Apex response to a React component hosted in VF?

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, react

I'm working in a simple POC to learn how to connect React-Visualforce-Apex. I have success inserting data generated in a React form to Salesforce, but now I would like to retrieve Salesforce data on demand and display it in my React component hosted in Visualforce.

**What I did:**

1. Created a VF page
2. Hosted my React app for testing using a script and exposing my localhost as recommended here https://rajaraodv.medium.com/developing-react-redux-apps-in-salesforce-s-visualforce-3ad7be560d1c
3. Called a remote Apex method using "Visualforce Remoting", successfully querying my data (just a list of fake leads).

**Question:**

How do I pass my returns back to the React component?

**Visualforce page**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" controller="PreApp_Controller">
<script type="text/javascript">
    let allLeads = [];
    function getLeads() {
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.PreApp_Controller.getLeads}', handleResult);
    }

    function handleResult(result, event) {            
        this.allLeads = result;           
    }
</script>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="root">
       <script src="MY_REACT_APP_URL" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

**My React App**

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
export default function Leads() {
   let leads = () => {
   getLeads();
};

return (
<>
  <Button
    color="primary"
    variant="contained"
    onClick={() => leads()}
    style={{ margin: 10 }}
  >
    Get Leads
  </Button>

  <ul>
    {allLeads.map((lead) => (
      <li>{lead.LastName}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</>
);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you need to call the server, you need a Promise, so:

```
function getLeads() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        "{!$RemoteAction.PreApp_Controller.getLeads}",
        resolve
      );
    } catch(e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
}
```

And in your React code:

```
export default async function leads() {
   const allLeads = await getLeads();
   this.setState({ allLeads });
};
```

I'm not an expert at React, so you might need some additional work, but this syntax should be pretty close.